# Hibernate ValidationQuery setup java bean

Tags: hibernate, spring-jdbc

i am trying to validate queries before any database action and if database connection fails there should be reconnect option without adding properties in datasource code is working fine.

following is my code

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
public class DatabaseConfig {

  @Value("${db.driver}")
  private String DB_DRIVER;

  @Value("${db.password}")
  private String DB_PASSWORD;

  @Value("${db.url}")
  private String DB_URL;

  @Value("${db.username}")
  private String DB_USERNAME;

  @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
  private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

  @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
  private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

  @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
  private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

  @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
  private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
//    DataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
//    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

    Properties configProps = new Properties();
       configProps.put("db.validationQuery", "SELECT 1");
       configProps.put("db.testOnBorrow", true);
       configProps.put("testWhileIdle", true);

    dataSource.setConnectionProperties(configProps);
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return sessionFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = 
        new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }

}
```

but it gives me error

```
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/ehydromet/dao/impl/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: session factory is null in com/ehydromet/dao/impl/DatabaseConfig.class,  because of which application is getting initialized, check your configuration

Comment: @TarunJain this error came up when i add this line  `dataSource.setConnectionProperties(configProps);` if i remove this line code works fine